# Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase/analytics' in React Js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

I have install newer version of firebase by  `npm install -g firebase` in few days ago .
Today I am making react app where I need firebase . So That is why I am trying import some firebase functions stuff in my react app by
 `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";` But, When I import this `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";` got this error massage
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase/analytics'` 
I how to fixed this problem ???

> place note : I have already firebase globally !!!

Comment: Can you share your code?  Also can you try just installing Firebase in your project and not globally?

Comment: when I install locally , I sow everything seems ok , but I when I install globally , I found error called modules not found .

Comment: When you install Firebase globally it won't be added to your project's `package.json` as a dependency.

Comment: should I need to add firebase to package.json ? how ?